# TypeError: jQuery.atmosphere is undefined packed.js:2261

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, hibernate, richfaces

Does someone already had this error :

TypeError: jQuery.atmosphere is undefined packed.js:2261 ?

I didn't find any documentation about this and no way to find a issue.(I added all dependencies needed)

Here is my test.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition template="/pages/template/template.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
xmlns:b="http://richfaces.org/sandbox/bootstrap"
lang="fr">

<ui:define name="body">
  <h:head>

    <h:outputScript name="javax.faces:jsf.js" />

    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" />

</h:head>
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="4">
        <h:outputLabel value="Message:" />
        <h:inputText id="messageInput" styleClass="message" value="#    {richBean.message}">
        </h:inputText>

        <a4j:commandButton value="Send" action="#{richBean.sendMessage()}"
            execute="@form" render="messageInput" />

        <rich:messages for="messageInput" />
    </h:panelGrid>


</h:form>

<h:form>
   <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <a4j:push address="pushCdi"
            ondataavailable="jQuery('&lt;li /&gt;').prependTo('#messages').text(event.rf.data)" />

        <ul id="messages" />
    </h:panelGrid> 


</h:form>

</ui:define>
```

My RichBean.java :

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicKey;
import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicsContext;
import org.richfaces.cdi.push.Push;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMappings;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicKey;
import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicsContext;
import org.richfaces.log.Logger;
import org.richfaces.log.RichfacesLogger;

@ManagedBean(name = "richBean")
@Scope(value = "session")
@URLMappings(mappings = { @URLMapping(id = "rich", pattern = "/test", viewId = "/test.xhtml") })
@Named
public class RichBean {

    public static final String PUSH_CDI_TOPIC = "pushCdi";

    private String message;

   @Push(topic = PUSH_CDI_TOPIC)
   @Inject
   Event<String> pushEvent;

     public void sendMessage() {
       pushEvent.fire(message);
       message = "";
    }

}
```

And Template.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" lang="fr">

    <ui:remove> 

    </ui:remove>

    <html>
        <c:set var="ctx" value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}" scope="request"/>
        <c:set var="myContext" value="#{request.serverName}:#{request.serverPort}#{request.contextPath}" scope="request" />

        <h:head>

            <title>#{messages['title']}<ui:insert name="title"></ui:insert></title>

            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;IE=7,chrome=1" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <meta charset="utf-8" />

            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private" />
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-stale=0" />

            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${ctx}/favicon.ico" />
            <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="${ctx}/favicon.ico" />

            <!-- CSS -->

            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />

            <link href="${ctx}/resources/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css" media="screen" />

            <link href="${ctx}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css" media="screen" />

            <link href="${ctx}/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css" media="screen" />

            <link href="${ctx}/resources/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css" media="screen" />

            <link href="${ctx}/resources/css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css" media="screen" />

            <link href="${ctx}/resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css" media="screen" />

            <!-- CSS end -->

            <ui:insert name="headAdd" />

            <ui:remove>
                <!--  Enable usage of html5 with old browsers -->
            </ui:remove>

            <h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lt IE 9]&gt;" escape="false" />
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="html5.js" />
            <h:outputText value="&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />

            <ui:remove>
            </ui:remove>
            <h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lte IE 7]&gt;" escape="false" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{resource['css:styleIE.css']}" />
            <h:outputText value="&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />

        </h:head>       
        <h:body>

            <div id="container" class="wrapper">
                <header>
                    <ui:insert name="header">
                        <ui:include src="parts/header.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                </header>

                <ui:insert name="body">
                    <ui:include src="parts/body.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>

                <div class="push"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
                <div class="footer">
                    <ui:insert name="footer">
                        <ui:include src="parts/footer.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h:outputScript library="jquery" name="jquery.js" target="head" />
            <h:outputScript library="jquery" name="jquery-ui.js" target="head" />
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="moment.min.js" />
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" />
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="table.js" />

        <rich:jQuery selector=".stable tr:odd" query="addClass('odd-row')" />
        <rich:jQuery selector=".stable tr:even" query="addClass('even-row')" />
        <rich:jQuery selector=".stable tr" event="mouseover"
            query="jQuery(this).addClass('active-row')" />
        <rich:jQuery selector=".stable tr" event="mouseout"
            query="jQuery(this).removeClass('active-row')" />
        <rich:jQuery selector=".stable tr" event="click"
            query="jQuery('.click-row').removeClass('click-row');jQuery(this).addClass('click-row')" />

        <rich:notifyMessages showDetail="true" globalOnly="true" styleClass="my-alert alert-info" style="margin-top:15px;" stayTime="5000" nonblocking="true" />
</h:body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

My pom.xml :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>barApp</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>barApp</name>

        <properties>
            <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <richfaces.version>4.3.5.Final</richfaces.version>
            <hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate.version>
            <cxf.version>2.6.1</cxf.version>
        </properties>

        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
<artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
<version>${richfaces.version}</version>
<scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <version>0.0.1-Snapshot</version>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/application-${env}.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
<resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/jks</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/</warSourceDirectory>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Implementation-Environment>${env}</Implementation-Environment>
                                <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>

            <finalName>barApp</finalName>
        </build>
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>tc6</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>dev</env>
                </properties>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    </dependency>       
                </dependencies>
            </profile>
            <profile>
                <id>jboss6</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>dev</env>
                </properties>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
<artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
   <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.12</version>
                        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- XML -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.04</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
                        <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </profile>
        </profiles>

        <dependencies>

            <!-- SPRING -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- HIBERNATE -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
  <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JSF -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0-b09</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0-b09</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- RICHFACES -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
                <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
          <artifactId>atmosphere-jquery</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.2</version>
          <type>war</type>
        </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

HTML Generated :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html><head>

                <title>ITcketing</title>

                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;IE=7,chrome=1" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <meta charset="utf-8" />

                <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
                <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
                <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
                <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private" />
                <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
                <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-stale=0" />


                <link href="/barApp/resources/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

                <link href="/barApp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                <link href="/barApp/resources/css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/styleIE.css.xhtml?ln=css" /><![endif]--><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml?ln=css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces.staticResource/4.3.5.Final/PackedCompressed/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces.staticResource/4.3.5.Final/PackedCompressed/packed/packed.js"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/barApp/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces.staticResource/4.3.5.Final/PackedCompressed/plain/packed/packed.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=jquery"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/jquery-ui.js.xhtml?ln=jquery"></script></head><body>

                <div id="container" class="wrapper">
                    <header>

        <table class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" width="100%" style="margin-top:-20px;">
            <tr>
                <td width="33%"><img src="/barApp/resources/css/images/logo.png" height="100px" />
                </td>
                <td valign="middle">

                        <h1 style="color: #003561;">ITcketing</h1>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
                    </header><head><script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script></head>
    <form id="j_idt25" name="j_idt25" method="post" action="/barApp/test" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt25" value="j_idt25" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><label>
Message:</label></td>
 <td><input id="j_idt25:messageInput" type="text" name="j_idt25:messageInput" value="32" class="message" /></td>
<td><input id="j_idt25:j_idt28" name="j_idt25:j_idt28" onclick="RichFaces.ajax(&quot;j_idt25:j_idt28&quot;,event,{&quot;incId&quot;:&quot;1&quot;} );return false;" value="Send" type="submit" /></td>
    <td><span class="rf-msgs " id="j_idt25:j_idt29"></span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-2268432026713773464:4752734078205348919" autocomplete="off" />
    </form>
    <form id="j_idt30" name="j_idt30" method="post" action="/barApp/test" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="j_idt30" value="j_idt30" />
    <span id="j_idt30:pushJms"><script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.Push.setPushResourceUrl("/barApp/rfRes/org.richfaces.resource.PushResource.xhtml");new RichFaces.ui.Push("j_idt30:pushJms",{"address":"pushTopicsContext","ondataavailable":function(event){RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{"parameters":{"javax.faces.behavior.event":"dataavailable","org.richfaces.ajax.component":"j_idt30:pushJms"} ,"sourceId":this} )}} );</script></span><table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><label>
    New UUID:</label></td>
    <td><div id="j_idt30:uuid">  
</div></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-2268432026713773464:4752734078205348919" autocomplete="off" />
    </form>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div style="padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
<div class="footer">
<footer class="bs-docs-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="container"><img src="/barApp/resources/css/images/logo.png" height="80px" />    
</div>
</footer>
</div>
</div><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.min.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/moment.min.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/barApp/javax.faces.resource/table.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script><span id="j_idt46" style="display: none;"><script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.jQuery.query({"selector":".stable tr:odd","query":"addClass('odd\u002Drow')"} );</script></span><span id="j_idt47" style="display: none;"><script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.jQuery.query({"selector":".stable tr:even","query":"addClass('even\u002Drow')"} );</script></span><span id="j_idt48" style="display: none;"><script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.jQuery.query({"selector":".stable tr","event":"mouseover","query":"jQuery(this).addClass('active\u002Drow')"} );</script></span><span id="j_idt49" style="display: none;"><script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.jQuery.query({"selector":".stable tr","event":"mouseout","query":"jQuery(this).removeClass('active\u002Drow')"} );</script></span><span id="j_idt50" style="display: none;"><script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.jQuery.query({"selector":".stable tr","event":"click","query":"jQuery('.click\u002Drow').removeClass('click\u002Drow');jQuery(this).addClass('click\u002Drow')"} );</script></span><span class="rf-ntf-msgs my-alert alert-info" id="j_idt51" style="margin-top:15px;"></span><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    new RichFaces.ui.Message("j_idt25:j_idt29",{"forComponentId":"j_idt25:messageInput","isMessages":true} )
    new RichFaces.ui.NotifyMessage("j_idt51",{"showDetail":true,"globalOnly":true,"isMessages":true} ,{"nonblocking":true,"stayTime":5000,"styleClass":"my\u002Dalert alert\u002Dinfo"} )
    });
    </script></body>
        </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: A bit of code, the markup where you add the scripts to your page, would be useful

Comment: I don't see references to your scripts in that page. I'm not a java expert, but I think I need the code of the HTML template. You can remove the `.java` file.

Comment: Don't see the link with the template,I don't think the error come from there but I also added it

Comment: Your error appears in packed.js. But I don't see where that script is included. I don't see any reference to jquery.atmospthere.js, either. Are you including it?

Comment: I added the dependencies in the pom.xml :           <dependency>
      <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
      <artifactId>atmosphere-jquery</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

Comment: @OscarPaz packed.js is RichFaces' resource file, it's included automatically and jQuery.atmosphere is part of it

Comment: And does that automatically add the `<script>` tag in the HTML? Could you post the html as the browser receives it?

Comment: I added it manually (     <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/atmosphere.js"></script>
    <!-- Application -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/application.js"></script> )
 and still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom resource handler to fix the `packed.js` file on the fly. This hack is based on the work done as part of the Liferay project and described [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/807297#807297) in an answer to an identical question. The custom resource handling code adds checks for the existance of jQuery.atmosphere to the packed.js file itself.

The code has been tested with Richfaces 4.3.3. Other releases of Richfaces might require tweaking either the JavaScript processing code and/or the file referenced in the `RICHFACES_PACKED_STATIC_RESOURCE` constant.

**Step1:** Create the custom resource handler.

CustomResourceHandler.java

```
package example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.faces.application.Resource;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceWrapper;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

/**
 * Fixes "jQuery.atmosphere is undefined" in packed.js from Richfaces when using resource optimization (packing, compression).
 * 
 * Based on: https://developer.jboss.org/message/807297#807297
 */
public class CustomResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

    // Private Constants
    private static final String RICHFACES_PACKED_STATIC_RESOURCE = "org.richfaces.staticResource/4.3.3.Final/Packed/packed/packed.js";

    private final ResourceHandler wrapped;

    public CustomResourceHandler(final ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
        Resource r = super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
        if (resourceName.equals(RICHFACES_PACKED_STATIC_RESOURCE)) {
            return new RichfacesPackedResourceWrapper(r);
        }
        return r;
    }

}

class RichfacesPackedResourceWrapper extends ResourceWrapper {

    private final Resource wrapped;

    public RichfacesPackedResourceWrapper(Resource r) {
        this.wrapped = r;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        InputStream s = super.getInputStream();
        String contents = fixRichFacesPackedDotJs(IOUtils.toString(s));

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
    }

    private String fixRichFacesPackedDotJs(String javaScriptText) {
        String token = "if (jQuery.atmosphere.requests.length > 0) {";

        int pos = javaScriptText.indexOf(token);
        if (pos > 0) {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            buf.append(javaScriptText.substring(0, pos));
            buf.append("if (!jQuery.atmosphere) { return; }; ");
            buf.append(javaScriptText.substring(pos));
            javaScriptText = buf.toString();
        }

        // jQuery.atmosphere.unsubscribe();
        token = "jQuery.atmosphere.unsubscribe();";
        pos = javaScriptText.indexOf(token);

        if (pos > 0) {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            buf.append(javaScriptText.substring(0, pos));
            buf.append("if (!jQuery.atmosphere) { return; }; ");
            buf.append(javaScriptText.substring(pos));
            javaScriptText = buf.toString();
        }

        return javaScriptText;
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Refer to the custom resource handler in your faces-config.xml (under `<application>`).

```
<resource-handler>example.CustomResourceHandler</resource-handler>
```

Answer (score 0):

RichFaces already comes with jQuery (1.8.3) and atmosphere, there is likely a conflict if you're including your own jquery.js

If you need to use a higher version of jQuery create META-INF/richfaces/static-resource-mappings.properties and put this line in it:

```
jquery.js=path/to/your/jquery.js
```

For more about re-routing resources look [here](http://planet.jboss.org/post/re_routing_jsf_resource_requests_with_richfaces_resource_mapping)

Edit:

Clean up your source files:

- in template.xhtml you have `<h:head>` and an inclusion of jquery.js
- in test.xhtml you're creating another `<h:head>` and including another jquery.js

Comment: Which file do you refer to with "my own jquery.js" ?

Comment: Can you update the question with the new files? The bean and pom.xml are not important.